# TFS 2013 is not copying build output to drop folder

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

We have just upgraded from VS 2010 / TFS 2010 to VS 2013 / TFS 2013.

Our old custom build definitions no longer work.  I am trying to simply create a new build definition that builds our solution and then copies it to an output folder as you can see below:

[image]

However ... it doesn't copy anything there but a logs directory:

---

[image]

---

Here's my build result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do the logs show? On the build server has the output been created in the src folder? I.e. src> project > bin as would happen on your local machine

Comment: @JustTFS - On the actual build server, it put my source files under `C:\Builds\11\Xxx`.  No bin folders though.  Log file only gives 1 warning: *C:\Builds\11\Xxx\src\Xxx.sln.metaproj : warning MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|x86" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.*

Comment: Have a look at the logs, or view the build through the web access and you can view the diagnostic log that way. If it's building, it must be outputting somewhere. Which template you using?

Comment: Trying to just use their default template.  Here's the error in the diagnostic log *TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory C:\Builds\11\Xxx\bin exists and that you have the appropriate permissions.*

Comment: have you tried both the DefaultTemplate.xaml and the DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml. One of them IIRC is left there so that your historic build defs carry on working with your upgraded build server.

Answer (score 2):

Ok in the process tab, where you select the sln to build you can specify the configuration and platform, set as per your sln file or leave blank. In vs right click your sln and look at the configuration, see what settings you have and replicate in the build definition. I.e. debug anycpu, release x64

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, only logs folder in the output (TFS2013). I solved it by setting:

`Process tab -> 2 Build -> 4 Output location` to `SingleFolder` (previously it said `AsConfigured`).